# App Scanner crashing on uploading the app file

Tags: ios, xcode4.5

I am facing issue with the private apis used in my application.So,I found that App Scanner application is a good tool for scanning those kind of issues.So i have installed it from [here](https://github.com/ChimpStudios/App-Scanner) .When trying to test my application it crashes giving me following crash report.

```
Process:         App Scanner [1951]
Path:            /Users/USER/Downloads/*/App Scanner.app/Contents/MacOS/App Scanner
Identifier:      com.chimpstudios.appscanner
Version:         1.4 (1.4.1)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [137]

Date/Time:       2013-06-18 12:28:57.620 +0530
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.5 (11G63)
Report Version:  9

Interval Since Last Report:          571103 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           13
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  938 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   7
Anonymous UUID:                      EC833868-1E25-4F4F-BC83-52C9B937E8A7

Crashed Thread:  8

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
objc[1951]: garbage collection is OFF
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSConcreteData subdataWithRange:]: range {1651465984, 1633641322} exceeds data length 4295932'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff92809f56 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff96085d5e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff92809d8a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff92809d14 +[NSException raise:format:] + 116
    4   Foundation                          0x00007fff946b9a4b -[NSData(NSData) subdataWithRange:] + 291
    5   App Scanner                         0x000000010000376c App Scanner + 14188
    6   Foundation                          0x00007fff9470a72a -[NSThread main] + 68
    7   Foundation                          0x00007fff9470a6a2 __NSThread__main__ + 1575
    8   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff984308bf _pthread_start + 335
    9   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff98433b75 thread_start + 13
)

terminate called throwing an exception
abort() called

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9854667a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff98545d71 mach_msg + 73
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9279650c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 188
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9279ec74 __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9279e486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff965892bf RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 277
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff9659056d ReceiveNextEventCommon + 355
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff965903fa BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff992a1779 _DPSNextEvent + 659
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff992a107d -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 135
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9929d9b9 -[NSApplication run] + 470
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff99519eac NSApplicationMain + 867
12  com.chimpstudios.appscanner     0x0000000100001074 0x100000000 + 4212

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff985487e6 kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff92724786 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 923
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff92723316 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54

Thread 2:: WebCore: LocalStorage
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff98547bca __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff98434274 _pthread_cond_wait + 840
2   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff93546a60 WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 64
3   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff8efcdf9a WTF::MessageQueue<WebCore::LocalStorageTask>::waitForMessage() + 132
4   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff8efcdef3 WebCore::LocalStorageThread::threadEntryPoint() + 99
5   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff8efcde3b WebCore::LocalStorageThread::threadEntryPointCallback(void*) + 9
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff984308bf _pthread_start + 335
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff98433b75 thread_start + 13
```

Can anybody let me know what's the issue as it is not crashing in any of the device nor in the simulator?

Comment: I've got the same issue, No luck here.